# Odin write image after phone not working samsung A10S

Tags: samsung, odin

I try install twrp using Odin. AP image write then my phone not working. All key combo not working. My phone Samsung A10s try write samsung A10 this is maybe my fault. How can i fix it.

Comment: If your phone seems hardbricked (doesn't do anything), try this guide
https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-sm-a107-mtk6765-unbrick-your-samsung-galaxy-a10s-stuck-on-a-black-screen-recognized-as-preloader-usb-vcom-and-cycling-rebooting.4322581/
Btw I am stuck on the same boat as you, I have a working phone but just can't get to twrp after flashing....
P.S. The above Guide will work with A107F as well